# opscenter 6.0 - Add Existing Cluster Protocol error

Tags: cassandra, datastax, opscenter

I have installed DSE 5.0 and configured 4 node cluster on AWS. Now i am trying to install DataStax Opscenter 6.0 to connect to this cluster. working Cluster is accessible and verifiable using Spark UI page.

While trying to configure opscenter (installed on other RHEL machine in same network), i am getting strange protocol error- and i cant add existing cluster to opscenter.

```
2016-07-05 15:47:07+0100 []  WARN: [control connection] Error connecting to 10.20.21.60: Unexpected response during Connection setup: ProtocolError('Server protocol version (4) does not match the specified driver protocol version (2). Consider setting Cluster.protocol_version to 4.',)
2016-07-05 15:47:07+0100 [] ERROR: Control connection failed to connect, shutting down Cluster: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {u'10.20.21.60': ProtocolError("Unexpected response during Connection setup: ProtocolError('Server protocol version (4) does not match the specified driver protocol version (2). Consider setting Cluster.protocol_version to 4.',)",)})
2016-07-05 15:47:07+0100 []  INFO: Starting factory <cassandra.io.twistedreactor.TwistedConnectionClientFactory instance at 0x3229f80>
2016-07-05 15:47:07+0100 []  INFO: Stopping factory <cassandra.io.twistedreactor.TwistedConnectionClientFactory instance at 0x3229f80>
2016-07-05 15:47:07+0100 []  WARN: [control connection] Error connecting to 10.20.21.61: Unexpected response during Connection setup: ProtocolError('Server protocol version (4) does not match the specified driver protocol version (2). Consider setting Cluster.protocol_version to 4.',)</B>
2016-07-05 15:47:07+0100 [] ERROR: Control connection failed to connect, shutting down Cluster: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {u'10.20.21.61': ProtocolError("Unexpected response during Connection setup: ProtocolError('Server protocol version (4) does not match the specified driver protocol version (2). Consider setting Cluster.protocol_version to 4.',)",)})
2016-07-05 15:47:07+0100 []  INFO: Starting factory <cassandra.io.twistedreactor.TwistedConnectionClientFactory instance at 0x327f050>
2016-07-05 15:47:07+0100 []  INFO: Stopping factory <cassandra.io.twistedreactor.TwistedConnectionClientFactory instance at 0x327f050>
2016-07-05 15:47:07+0100 []  WARN: [control connection] Error connecting to 10.20.21.62: Unexpected response during Connection setup: ProtocolError('Server protocol version (4) does not match the specified driver protocol version (2). Consider setting Cluster.protocol_version to 4.',)
2016-07-05 15:47:07+0100 [] ERROR: Control connection failed to connect, shutting down Cluster: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {u'10.20.21.62': ProtocolError("Unexpected response during Connection setup: ProtocolError('Server protocol version (4) does not match the specified driver protocol version (2). Consider setting Cluster.protocol_version to 4.',)",)})
2016-07-05 15:47:07+0100 []  INFO: Starting factory <cassandra.io.twistedreactor.TwistedConnectionClientFactory instance at 0x322c440>
2016-07-05 15:47:07+0100 []  INFO: Stopping factory <cassandra.io.twistedreactor.TwistedConnectionClientFactory instance at 0x322c440>
2016-07-05 15:47:07+0100 []  WARN: [control connection] Error connecting to 10.20.21.63: Unexpected response during Connection setup: ProtocolError('Server protocol version (4) does not match the specified driver protocol version (2). Consider setting Cluster.protocol_version to 4.',)
2016-07-05 15:47:07+0100 [] ERROR: Control connection failed to connect, shutting down Cluster: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {u'10.20.21.63': ProtocolError("Unexpected response during Connection setup: ProtocolError('Server protocol version (4) does not match the specified driver protocol version (2). Consider setting Cluster.protocol_version to 4.',)",)})
2016-07-05 15:47:07+0100 []  WARN: ProcessingError while calling CreateClusterConfController: Unable to connect to cluster. Error is: Unable to connect to any seed nodes, tried [u'10.20.21.60', u'10.20.21.61', u'10.20.21.62', u'10.20.21.63']
```

I have read somewhere that DSE opscenter have problem in connecting with apache cassandra 3.0 but in my case its all Datastax DSE 5.0 & DataStax Opscenter 6.0.

anyone have any pointers or prior experience to deal with this error for opscenter? 
thanks for yours help well in advance :)

Thanks.

Comment: Those look like messages from OpsC 5.x, are you sure you are running OpsCenter 6.0? OpsC 5.x does not support DSE 5.0.

Comment: Thanks Chris , I will verify opscenter vresion tomorrow as servers are down now. I followed datastax instructions e.g. sudo yum install opscenter from datastax repo assuming i will get the latest version 6.0 . I followed this url for installation - http://docs.datastax.com/en/opscenter/latest/opsc/install/opscInstallRHEL_t.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until recently, the docs at http://docs.datastax.com/en/opscenter/latest/opsc/install/opscInstallRHEL_t.html listed the "community" rpm repository, which is where we distributed OpsCenter versions up to 5.2.x. With OpsCenter 6.0.0, we've begun distributing through the "enterprise" rpm repository to reflect that we're now compatible with DSE only (and no longer compatible with non-DSE distributions of Cassandra).

The effect of this is that if you followed the instructions on that page, you'd get OpsCenter 5.2.latest instead of OpsCenter 6.0.0, which is incompatible with DSE 5.0. The instructions now have been updated, and if you switch from the community to the enterprise repo and upgrade to OpsCenter 6.0.0, your problems should be resolved.

Edit: In the interest of full disclosure, I should note that I work for DataStax developing OpsCenter.

Comment: Thanks Mike. I was able to realise the community vs enterprise repo issue with download and did correct it but headed to another problem - opscenter process get killed on startup. I will post my steps as answer as there is size limitation in comments,